# MySQL error with dates

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL tells me I have a wrong syntax, but I don't know where. Can anyone help me?

```
$dt = $xml->item->parameter[2];
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($dt));
$query = sprintf("select * from me,val where group_id=%s AND m_id= me_id AND time_stamp <= $to",mysql_real_escape_string($gid));
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

The parsing to a date works. Thanks in advance.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '23:59:59' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to put the date (`$to`) in single quotes:

```
"select * from me,val where group_id=%s AND m_id= me_id AND time_stamp <= '$to'"
```

to avoid these kind (and a lot of other) problems, you might want to think about using prepared statements (take a look at [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) instead of the old (and deprecated) `mysql_*`-functions.

Comment: Thanks at first, it fixed that problem but brought me a knew. ^^
To be honest, I already had PDO in use but I couldn't find out how this "($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)" has to look like in PDO. May you can help me?

Comment: `$row = $result_object->fetch()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = sprintf("select * from me,val where group_id=%s AND m_id= me_id AND time_stamp <= '$to'",mysql_real_escape_string($gid));
```

or

```
$query = sprintf("select * from me,val where group_id=%s AND m_id= me_id AND time_stamp <= %s",mysql_real_escape_string($gid),$to);
```

you should enclose `date` in single quotes